# Interpolation of very sparse meshgrid for country heatmap generation

Tags: python, interpolation, heatmap

I have a dataset of incidents per country over time, and I want to create a changing heatmap over the period in the same time-step as the incidents. So far, I have:

```
        ax2 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Miller())
        ax2.set_global()
        ax2.coastlines()
        ax2.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, zorder=0)
        ax2.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linewidth=0.6)
        ax2.set_title('Second axis plot')

        grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (x2d, y2d), method='cubic', fill_value=0)
        print grid_z0

        cnt = ax2.pcolormesh(lons_new, lats_new, grid_z0,
         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap = cmap, alpha = 0.5)

        plt.show()
```

Where

- Points/values are generated by assigning all points inside the
  country with the number of incidents (so for the first iteration):
  Argentina has all values of '1', U.K. has all values of '1'.
- x2d, y2d is:

  ```
     lats_new = np.linspace(-90, 90, 91)
     lons_new = np.linspace(-180, 180, 91)
     x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(lons_new, lats_new)
  ```

This generates:
[first incident](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saO1J.png)

What I am trying to achieve: interpolation based on distance (that is the two countries in the figure I've attached should be separate and red, fading out at the border). I've tried a few interpolation methods from scipy but nothing seems to do well (2d, as well as all from griddata).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using a gaussian filter to interpolate matrix before contouring:

1. Image as a binary matrix of incident values (one incident in U.K.,
   one in Argentina). Seen here as a color mesh:

   [Color mesh before Guassian filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4WqL.png)
2. Apply a guassian filter to the mask matrix over the world:

   ```
       sigma_y = 3.0
       sigma_x = 3.0

       sigma = [sigma_y, sigma_x]

       y = sp.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(grid_new, sigma, mode='constant')
   ```

Where grid_new is a 2D matrix of incident values. Color mesh after applying guassian filter: 
[Matrix after guassian filter seen as a pcolormesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWNiC.png)

3. Apply .contourf function to the guassian filtered matrix:
   [Contourf of gaussian filtered matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0RB0.png)